# Need help connected to datastax sandbox from windows 10 host running VirtualBox

Tags: datastax, windows-dev-center

1. Sandbox up and running in Virtual Box, bridged.   My VM's IP is ***192.168.14.200***.
2. I can connect to ops center from my windows host by going to http://192.168.14.200:8888, as well as from within the VM by browsing to http://127.0.0.1:8888.
3. I can run DevCenter from within the VM, whose connection is localhost:9042
4. I downloaded DevCenter to my Windows 10 host and setup a connection to ***192.168.14.200:9042***, which fails to connect:

   ```
   The specified host(s) could not be reached.
   All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /192.168.14.200:9042(com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/192.168.14.200:9042] Cannot connect))
   ```

I have the same problem from within my C# code that throws a connection exception.  I think if I can solve the DevCenter issue my C# code will work.

I have tried the following changes to the sandboxes cassandra.yaml file;

Change the listen_address by excluding it, changing it from localhost to ***127.0.0.1***, and ***192.168.14.200***, as well as with rpc_address.

At this point I am at a loss and any help just getting DevCenter working would be a great start.

Comment: what type of connection does the guest have? Bridged or NAT?

Comment: bridged, at the moment it is the only config that I have had that I can connect to the 8888 port to to view the Ops site in the browser.

Comment: If you're running a single node DSE you should have the listen and RPC addresses pointing to your VM's IP. You should also have your seed provider pointed there too. Please post your cassandra.yaml file. Lastly, I am not very good at troubleshooting these types of issues on Windows, but can you tell what is listening on 192.168.14.200:9042

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main goal was to get a development Cassandra instance running in VirtualBox on windows and connect to it using Datastax DevCenter from the Windows Host.  I was hoping to just use the Datastax sandbox, but I ultimately got it working using this method which was using Vagrant to setup Cassandra on an Ubuntu VM;

https://github.com/bcantoni/vagrant-cassandra/tree/master/1.Base
There is a very nice Youtube walkthrough and written instructions here.

After getting this to work, I made the following changes to cassandra.yaml;

```
Comment out listen_address  
Un-comment listen_interface: eth0

Comment out rpc_address  
Un-comment rpc_interface: eth1

kill the CassandraDaemon  
restart Cassandra.
```

I was able to use the ***10.211.54.10*** address from the windows host to connect via DevCenter.

Here is the network information of the Ubuntu VM which is hosting Cassandra.

```
vagrant@cassandra:~/apache-cassandra-3.4$ ifconfig  
eth0      
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:c9:24:d6  
      inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0  
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fec9:24d6/64 Scope:Link  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1  
      RX packets:138562 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
      TX packets:33785 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000  
      RX bytes:125767502 (125.7 MB)  TX bytes:2587641 (2.5 MB)  

eth1      
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:2e:5d:ae  
      inet addr:10.211.54.10  Bcast:10.211.54.255  Mask:255.255.255.0  
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe2e:5dae/64 Scope:Link  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1  
      RX packets:680 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
      TX packets:110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000  
      RX bytes:95365 (95.3 KB)  TX bytes:36810 (36.8 KB)  

lo        
Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0  
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host  
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1  
      RX packets:126277 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
      TX packets:126277 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0  
      RX bytes:6395285 (6.3 MB)  TX bytes:6395285 (6.3 MB)
```